# Converting the imperative root function to functional style in kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

The root function checks and traverse until it get the root element in the tree.

```
class NodeRoot(N: Int){
    private val id: IntArray = IntArray(N)
    init {
        (0..N-1).forEach{ id[it] = it }
    }

    fun root(i: Int): Int {
        var i = i
        while (i != id[i]) i = id[i]
        return i
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure with `while (i != id[i]) i = id[i]`? That looks awkward, considering the id array is just `0..N-1`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, here's how you can rewrite `root` to be functional:

```
tailrec fun root(i: Int): Int = if (i == id[i]) i else root(id[i])
```

The `tailrec` keyword lets the compiler know that it should compile this to a loop, which avoids allocations on the stack due to recursion.

However, I agree with [glee8e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832696/converting-the-imperative-root-function-to-functional-style-in-kotlin#comment74702399_43832696): There may be better ways to express this.

You can also avoid the `init` block and just pass a lambda to `IntArray` to initialize each element:

```
private val id: IntArray = IntArray(N) { it }
```